# How can I determine when a git ref was created?

Tags: git

This is not the question you think it is.

I want to know when a specific ref was created. I do not want to know what the author timestamp or the committer timestamp is.

For example: if I pull from a remote repo, which updates my local repo, I want to retrieve the timestamps of the time the local repo refs were created.

```
[remote-host]$ git show --format='%H %cD' refs/heads/master
25f2508a379adf2f8aa264afe6f7e5046943274a Mon, 1 Aug 2016 11:33:12 -0700

[remote-host]$ logout
Connection to remote-host closed.
[local-host]$ git fetch
remote: Counting objects: 165073, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (1836/1836)
remote: Total 1836 (delta 484), reused 1374 (delta 484)
Receiving objects: 100% (1836/1836), 4.10 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (484/484), completed with 262 local objects.
...
[local-host]$ git show --format='%H %cD' 25f2508a379adf2f8aa264afe6f7e5046943274a
25f2508a379adf2f8aa264afe6f7e5046943274a Mon, 1 Aug 2016 11:33:12 -0700

[local-host]$ date
Mon Aug  1 11:50:44 PDT 2016
```

The output I want is `Mon Aug  1 11:50:44 PDT 2016` (i.e. the time of the fetch), not the committer date which is correctly identical on both the remote and the local host.

I thought of using `git reflog`, but the output of that command is strangely void of any timestamp info.

Comment: I added an example to show why committer timestamp doesn't work (also flagging your comment as "non-constructive")

Comment: `%cD` is the commiter date, which you said is not what you want.

Comment: @user3137702, he is demonstrating how `%cD` does not provide the information he's looking for.  Read carefully the last four lines or so of the question, looking in particular at the output of the `git show` command, the `date` command, and the penultimate sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `git` tracks the information you're looking for, which is I think more accurately described as "the date a blob was created on my local system".

You could:

- First look for a loose blob with a matching content hash, and if you find it, assume the `mtime` of that blob is the time at which is was created on your system (since it shouldn't get modified by any subsequent operation):

  ```
  cid=25f2508a379adf2f8aa264afe6f7e5046943274a
  if test -f .git/objects/${cid:0:2}/${cid:2}; then
    ls -l .git/objects/${cid:0:2}/${cid:2}
  fi
  ```
- If you don't find a loose object, look through your pack files to find the corresponding content id, and if you find it, assume the `mtime` of the corresponding packfile is the date you want:

  ```
  for idx in .git/objects/pack/*.idx; do
    if git show-index < $idx | grep $cid; then
      ls -l ${idx/idx/pack}
      break
    fi
  done
  ```

Comment: I feared that this would be the answer. Do you mind if I modify the question to use "the date the blob was created on my local system"?

Comment: Wrap it up in a nice script, stick it on github, and become Internet Famous! :)

Answer (score -1):

Using `--date=short` or `--date=relative` / `--relative-date` (or indeed any of the date directives) will show you the time stamp of the reflog entry itself, rather than the time stamp of the commit, inside the `{...}` part:

```
$ git reflog torturetest --date=relative
8bb1189 torturetest@{3 days ago}: branch: Created from HEAD
$ git reflog torturetest --date=default
8bb1189 torturetest@{Fri Jul 29 00:17:04 2016 -0700}: branch: Created from HEAD
```

The main problem with this is that there's no guarantee that the `Created from` entry exists: it may never have been put into the reflog, or it may have expired.

Comment: In the example above, if I type `git reflog --date=default 25f2508a379adf2f8aa264afe6f7e5046943274a`, I get no output. It appears reflog doesn't take sha1s, or I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: reflogs are not Git objects and cannot be named by SHA-1.  The only valid arguments are reference names (e.g., `HEAD`, or a branch or remote-tracking branch name).  (Also, I answered before you had an example, and was working from your text about when the ref—by which I assumed you mean the reference itself—was created or updated.)